# Matematical operation between couple fo number in list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a even list of numbers:

```
lst = [2,3,4,1,6,7]
```

I need to subtract the second number of each couple and sum the result of all couples, below the result:

```
out = 3-2+1-4+7-6
```

Is there any elegant solution? Appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> sum(lst[1::2]) - sum(lst[::2])
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy way of doing this

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array([2,3,4,1,6,7])

print(np.sum(lst[1::2] - lst[::2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use enumerate

```
sum(e if c%2 else -e for c,e in enumerate(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```py
import numpy as np

lst = [2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7]
lst = np.array(lst)
# array([2 3 4 1 6 7])

lst = np.split(lst, len(lst) / 2)
# [array([2, 3]), array([4, 1]), array([6, 7])]

lst = [arr[1] - arr[0] for arr in lst]
# [1, -3, 1]

lst = sum(lst)

print(lst) # -1
```